# ASP.NET MVC form\controller routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm a bit new to MVC and have no idea why following issue happening.
According to tutorial we can handle form posts by this code:

**View:**

```
<form action = "/learning/Goto" method="GET">
        <input type="text"name="gotoUrl"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Goto"/>
</form>
```

where Learning is Controller and goto is method as I understood.

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult Goto(string gotoUrl)
 {
      return Redirect(gotoUrl);
 }
```

I have a question: all I did according to the tutorial video and it worked in the video. However I have some trouble.

In my view I have warning:
"Path E:\Programming\MVC_Learning\learning not found" in the following line:

```
<form action = "/learning/Goto" method="GET">
```

I think that need to setup path to Controller folder. But what I don't understand the most the fact that it works and really redirect to input address but only in this form: "http:// mysite.net". If I write mysite.net I get exception 
**HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**

Requested URL
http://localhost:64074/learning/mysite.net
Physical Path      E:\Programming\C_SHARP\MVC_Learning\MVC_Learning\learning\mysite.net

So could somebody explain me following:
1. Why it works with http but does not work without?
2. Why I get warning on

```
<form action = "/learning/Goto" method="GET">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action url wrong, Instead of "/learning/Goto" use(Most Preferred way in MVC)

```
<form action = "@Url.Action("Goto","learning")" method="GET">
```

or just remove "/" and

```
<form action = "learning/Goto" method="GET">
```